# Tensorboard for Tensorflow.JS under Windows 10

Tags: tensorboard, tensorflow.js

I spent long time trying to figure out how to install and run [Tensorboard](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard) on a Windows 10 machine, for projects that are using [Tensorflow.JS](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs)

Has anybody ever made this work? If so, please share the steps.

I have [Tensorflow.JS](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs) working fine with my GPU under Windows 10, but I cannot find any documentation for using [Tensorboard](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard) under the combination of Windows + [Tensorflow.JS](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs)

##### Environment:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Node.JS v14.17.3
- Python v3.8.9
- Tensorflow v2.5.0
- Tensorflow.JS v3.8.0

I'm using `@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu`, with RTX3080Ti, which works fine.

Comment: This issue is being tracked in :- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/5189

Comment: @TensorflowSupport It doesn't seem of much help there, as the author suggested that Windows + Tensorflow.JS aren't supported, and closed the issue. I don't see how this helps anybody.

Comment: Maybe this is too hacky, but it's how I handle JS and tensorflow interactions (I actually don't even use tensorflow js in favor of the python versions, but I'm backend).. Can you just install tensorboard into a python environment and then call a simple python script running tensorboard with your favorite JS calling Python method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [here](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_node/3.8.0/#node.tensorBoard) shows how to integrate `tfjs` in node with the `tensorboad`. But it requires `tensorboard` to be aldready installed.

When using it `tensorflow` with python, `tensorboard` comes as a dependency of the `tensorflow` package. But using it in js requires to install the tensorboard package as a standalone package.

```
pip install tensorboard
```

So far, pip is the only way I think to install `tensorboard`. If the command fails, it probably must have to do with the python version, but it can be changed easily